# .Net Datagridview does not display emoji

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My datagridview displays a string containing emoji that's blanked out:

[image: datagridview sample]

However, when I cut and paste over to MS Word, it displays correctly:

[image: Word doc sample]

I thought it's a font issue, but changing fonts to not avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Word. Does the *font* support those characters? If not, you'll have to use a different font

Comment: BTW instead of posting an image of a Word document that nobody can copy into code, post the emojis in the question itself as *text*. Also post the code you use to display those characters. It could be that they are stored or loaded as ASCII instead of Unicode from their source.

Comment: I used `` and they worked well.

Comment: this is the problem doing things like :) produces a smiley which is a different font to the text you were typing.. to provide whatever emoji..

Comment: No repro binding to an array of objects. Typing emojis into a label's Text property works. Binding a DataGridView to an array of objects containing emojis works, eg `new MyDTO{Name="Test",Text=""}`

Comment: @BugFinder emojis are well defined in the Unicode character set. Using the emoji keyobard on Windows 10 (Win + .) I was able to type those emojis directly into a label property and source code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos however as I said, if you type :) in word or outlook it converts to a smiley face, this is NOT using the emoji keyboard on win 10 its been this way since a long time.l this actually uses a different font and substitutes :) for a J in windings I think it is

Comment: @BugFinder that's not an emoji. That's two characters that some *applications* will display as if it were a single one, typically by *replacing* them with a single character. That's not what the question is about. Emojis are actual characters.

Comment: @BugFinder in fact, what you describe is an *autocorrect* feature in Office that replaces certain character sequences like `:)` or `==>` with another character. You can define your own replacements if I remember correctly